# Google Drive API Webhook

Tags: python-3.x, flask, google-api, google-drive-api, webhooks

I have set up a google drive webhook through the "watch property"(https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/watch) and it is working well and submitting a response as soon as any changes are detected on the watch file. However, the request body (i.e.posted_data=request.get_data( )) as below comes back empty (i.e. None). I have tried other options such as request.json but still empty. Does anyone have any ideas on what I am possibly doing wrong? My Python Flask webhook code is below and works well (i.e. any file updates are posted) except that it returns an empty data type (i.e.posted_data=request.get_data( ) is None). Any suggestions are highly appreciated!

```
  from datetime import datetime
  from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
  import pytz

  def get_timestamp():
     dt=datetime.now(pytz.timezone('US/Central'))  
     return dt.strftime(("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))


  app = Flask(__name__)

  @app.route('/webhook', methods=['POST','GET'])
  def webhook():
      if request.method=='GET':
          return '<h1> This is a webhook listener!</h1>'
      if request.method == 'POST':
          posted_data=request.get_data( )
          print("We have received a request =====>",posted_data)   
          cur_date=get_timestamp()
          print("Date and time of update ====>",cur_date)
          http_status=jsonify({'status':'success'}),200
      else:
          http_status='',400
      return http_status

  if __name__ == '__main__':
      app.run(port=5000)
```

Comment: what does print(request.get_data()) outputs?

Comment: @Akib it returns a None type ...it's empty.

Comment: Are you using an IDE? Can you inspect what is in your request object ?

Comment: @Akib I have the webhook hosted on a server but printing the output. Google will not allow me to do these tests locally as they have to be posted on a server url and also ssl enabled (i.e. https).

Comment: I have managed to solve this problem. Apparently, google posts the response through the headers (i.e. request.headers instead of request.get_data( )).

Comment: You should post your solution as an answer with steps you took and images. So it will help others

Answer (score 0):

The above code works except that google will post their response as headers (i.e. request.headers). See updated code below.

```
from datetime import datetime
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
import pytz



def get_timestamp():
    dt=datetime.now(pytz.timezone('US/Central'))  
    return dt.strftime(("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))


app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/webhook', methods=['POST','GET'])
def webhook():
    if request.method=='GET':
        return '<h1> This is a webhook listener!</h1>'
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print(request.headers)
        cur_date=get_timestamp()
        print("Date and time of update ====>",cur_date)
        http_status=jsonify({'status':'success'}),200
    else:
        http_status='',400
    return http_status

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(port=5000)
```

Comment: I'm working on the same API's. TBH i'd expect better docs from Google. There is no explanation whatsoever on the Webhook call and its all trial and error development.